# Best and easiest method of passing map coordinates to Google maps

Tags: javascript, java, android, sqlite, google-maps

Hi I have developed an app that has over 100 set locations that can be accessed but at the moment I have them set in individual classes meaning I have over 100 location map classes which is lazy and far from ideal.

I want to create a database where I can store the locations and have the map class retrieve the locations when needed.

What is the best and easiest way to achieve it using sqlite.

So far I setup a database with longitude and latitude as integers and primary keys and setup a name field as an identifier but I am struggling with how to execute the sqlite.

Comment: Why not just use a SQLite database with entries for each location, and load them into the map when it loads??

Comment: What method would you recommend to use in a Map class

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay strictly Java and Android without using even small snippets of SQLite and just want to load them from your Project's rescources it's not very flexible, but not too hard. So if you just need the Coordinates of longitude and Latitude in `float`, you can simply load them into a `PointF` array and if you also want a Corresponding Name you can use `HashMap`, otherwise you'll need a custom Coordinate Class or just do whatever you need with those coordinates rightaway.

So for the XML-part you basically two options:

1. You create a `string-array` and use a splitter-character to split at
   name, latitude, longitude and whateer else you need. Easier to
   organize in XML, harder to code (you might get erros with that `parseFloat`):

   XML (splitter-character is ";"):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <string-array name="map_coordinates">
           <item>New York;40.7127837;-74.0059413</item>
           <item>London;51.5073509;-0.1277583</item>
           <item>Paris;48.856614;2.3522219</item>
       </string-array>
   </resources>
   ```

   Code to retrieve into `HashMap<String,PointF>`:

   ```
   HashMap<String, PointF> mapCoordinates = new HashMap<>();
   String[] mapStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.map_coordinates);

   for (String mapString: mapStrings) {
       String[] mapStringParts = mapString.split(";");
       String name = mapStringParts[0];
       float longitude = Float.parseFloat(mapStringParts[1]);
       float lattitude = Float.parseFloat(mapStringParts[2]);

       /*If you want to do something with your entries here,
       you don't have to use HashMap, just an idea*/
       mapCoordinates.put(name, new PointF(longitude, lattitude));
   }

   //To find the location of a specific name use:
   PointF location = mapCoordinates.get("NAME");
   ```
2. You can use multiple arrays to store name, longitude, lattitude and
   other stuff seperately. With many items it's hard to see which
   longitude belongs to what lattitude, but there won't be anny error
   possibilites, although you must use `integer` instead of `float`, so just
   divide them by a specific value to shift the floating point:

   XML:

   ```
   <string-array name="map_names">
       <item>New York</item>
       <item>London</item>
       <item>Paris</item>
   </string-array>
   <integer-array name="map_longitudes">
       <item>407127837</item>
       <item>515073509</item>
       <item>48856614</item>
   </integer-array>
   <integer-array name="map_lattitudes">
       <item>-740059413</item>
       <item>-1277583</item>
       <item>2352222</item>
   </integer-array>
   ```

   Code:

   HashMap mapCoordinates = new HashMap<>();

   ```
   String[] mapNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.map_names);
   int[] mapLongitudes = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.map_longitudes);
   int[] mapLatitudes = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.map_lattitudes);
   for (int i = 0; i < mapNames.length; i++) {
       String name = mapNames[i];
       float longitude = ((float) mapLongitudes[i]) / 1000000;
       float latitude = ((float) mapLatitudes[i]) / 1000000;

       //Again, do whatever you want with those values
       mapCoordinates.put(name, new PointF(longitude, latitude));
   }

   //To find the location of a specific name use:
   PointF location = mapCoordinates.get("NAME");
   ```

But I would recommend looking into SQLite databases as this kind of storing Tables like coordinates with names is exactly what they are built for.

Hope this helps :)